# Convert date to word

Tags: vb.net

I am developing software that need to convert date as a text. Like cheqe printing software display amount as a text.

For an example `2017/02/28` should be displayed as

> 28th of February Two Thousand and Seventeen

I am using vb.net 2008. can anyone direct me to how to approach this?

Comment: The day part is easy because you can use `Date.ToString` but there is no easy way to turn the year into words.  You just have to write code to implement the logic.  The first step in doing that is to determine what the logic is.  That part isn't even a programming problem and certainly isn't a VB.NET problem.

Comment: 1,118 rep 11 silver and 28 bronze and u ask a question like that????

Comment: @Trevor i am new to vb.net programming. If you do not know to answer. please ignore this question. Its a shame that your type people in this forum. I earn this reputation for Java script.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney thanks for your comment. yes i tried some ways. But I need to know if there is a easy way to do this in vb.net. Thanks again

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's VB or whatever it is.... the logic is the same... the question does not follow the SO guidelines... I don't mean to be rude... I'm just surprised...

Comment: I created a algorithm for this. But I need to know is vb.net have proper function to do this. thats all

Comment: Nothing I know of, just got to split it up and to churn through the # to text mappings. However if you plan on using it in a multi-lingual environment.. that's going to add a few more wrinkles.

Comment: Thats right. I have noticed that

Comment: I changed the date to ISO format as using non-ISO formats can be confusing.

Comment: Don't edit the question or its title just to indicate that the problem has been solved. That's what accepting an answer is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok to achieve what you are asking, follow these steps.
In your project, Click on `Project` and select `Manage NuGet Packages...`
Once you are in there and the page has loaded, click on `Browse` and type in the search box `Humanizer`
 It will show you from 25 - 30 search results, in your case you want to select `Humanizer.Core.uk` select it and install it.
 Once that is installed close out of the `Nuget Package Manager`and follow the code below that I have quickly written up for you.

```
Imports Humanizer

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(dateToText())
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Private Function dateToText() As String

    Dim NumbersToText = DateTime.Now.Year.ToWords()
    Dim MonthName = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month)
    Dim dayNum As String = ""

    Select Case DateTime.Now.Day
        Case 1
            dayNum = "st"
            Exit Select
        Case 2
            dayNum = "nd"
            Exit Select
        Case 3
            dayNum = "rd"
            Exit Select
        Case 21
            dayNum = "st"
            Exit Select
        Case 22
            dayNum = "nd"
            Exit Select
        Case 23
            dayNum = "rd"
            Exit Select
        Case 31
            dayNum = "st"
            Exit Select
        Case Else
            dayNum = "th"
            Exit Select
    End Select

    Dim result = Date.Now.Day & dayNum & " of " & MonthName & " " & NumbersToText
    Return result

End Function

End Module
```

This was done in a console application, use the same method if you are using a windows form application
`output: 14th of February two thousand and seventeen`

Comment: Converts numbers to English

Comment: Nice but I must try to implement a class for number to word. So I can replace Humanizer. Thanks for this answer

Comment: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=8704 this will do Number to Word convertion

Answer (score 0):

combining @Werdna answer and [This example](http://freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=8704) I could able to create a class for convert Date to word. So I could able to replace *Humanizer* with [This example](http://freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=8704). Here is the class

```
Public Class NumbersToWord


    Dim mOnesArray(8) As String
    Dim mOneTensArray(9) As String
    Dim mTensArray(7) As String
    Dim mPlaceValues(4) As String


    Public Sub New()

        mOnesArray(0) = "one"
        mOnesArray(1) = "two"
        mOnesArray(2) = "three"
        mOnesArray(3) = "four"
        mOnesArray(4) = "five"
        mOnesArray(5) = "six"
        mOnesArray(6) = "seven"
        mOnesArray(7) = "eight"
        mOnesArray(8) = "nine"

        mOneTensArray(0) = "ten"
        mOneTensArray(1) = "eleven"
        mOneTensArray(2) = "twelve"
        mOneTensArray(3) = "thirteen"
        mOneTensArray(4) = "fourteen"
        mOneTensArray(5) = "fifteen"
        mOneTensArray(6) = "sixteen"
        mOneTensArray(7) = "seventeen"
        mOneTensArray(8) = "eightteen"
        mOneTensArray(9) = "nineteen"

        mTensArray(0) = "twenty"
        mTensArray(1) = "thirty"
        mTensArray(2) = "forty"
        mTensArray(3) = "fifty"
        mTensArray(4) = "sixty"
        mTensArray(5) = "seventy"
        mTensArray(6) = "eighty"
        mTensArray(7) = "ninety"

        mPlaceValues(0) = "hundred"
        mPlaceValues(1) = "thousand"
        mPlaceValues(2) = "million"
        mPlaceValues(3) = "billion"
        mPlaceValues(4) = "trillion"

    End Sub


    Protected Function GetOnes(ByVal OneDigit As Integer) As String

        GetOnes = ""

        If OneDigit = 0 Then
            Exit Function
        End If

        GetOnes = mOnesArray(OneDigit - 1)

    End Function


    Protected Function GetTens(ByVal TensDigit As Integer) As String

        GetTens = ""

        If TensDigit = 0 Or TensDigit = 1 Then
            Exit Function
        End If

        GetTens = mTensArray(TensDigit - 2)

    End Function


    Public Function ConvertNumberToWords(ByVal NumberValue As String) As String

        Dim Delimiter As String = " "
        Dim TensDelimiter As String = "-"
        Dim mNumberValue As String = ""
        Dim mNumbers As String = ""
        Dim mNumWord As String = ""
        Dim mFraction As String = ""
        Dim mNumberStack() As String
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim mOneTens As Boolean = False

        ConvertNumberToWords = ""

        ' validate input
        Try
            j = CDbl(NumberValue)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ConvertNumberToWords = "Invalid input."
            Exit Function
        End Try

        ' get fractional part {if any}
        If InStr(NumberValue, ".") = 0 Then
            ' no fraction
            mNumberValue = NumberValue
        Else
            mNumberValue = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(NumberValue, InStr(NumberValue, ".") - 1)
            mFraction = Mid(NumberValue, InStr(NumberValue, ".")) ' + 1)
            mFraction = Math.Round(CSng(mFraction), 2) * 100

            If CInt(mFraction) = 0 Then
                mFraction = ""
            Else
                mFraction = "&& " & mFraction & "/100"
            End If
        End If
        mNumbers = mNumberValue.ToCharArray

        ' move numbers to stack/array backwards
        For j = mNumbers.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
            ReDim Preserve mNumberStack(i)

            mNumberStack(i) = mNumbers(j)
            i += 1
        Next

        For j = mNumbers.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Select Case j
                Case 0, 3, 6, 9, 12
                    ' ones  value
                    If Not mOneTens Then
                        mNumWord &= GetOnes(Val(mNumberStack(j))) & Delimiter
                    End If

                    Select Case j
                        Case 3
                            ' thousands
                            mNumWord &= mPlaceValues(1) & Delimiter

                        Case 6
                            ' millions
                            mNumWord &= mPlaceValues(2) & Delimiter

                        Case 9
                            ' billions
                            mNumWord &= mPlaceValues(3) & Delimiter

                        Case 12
                            ' trillions
                            mNumWord &= mPlaceValues(4) & Delimiter
                    End Select


                Case Is = 1, 4, 7, 10, 13
                    ' tens value
                    If Val(mNumberStack(j)) = 0 Then
                        mNumWord &= GetOnes(Val(mNumberStack(j - 1))) & Delimiter
                        mOneTens = True
                        Exit Select
                    End If

                    If Val(mNumberStack(j)) = 1 Then
                        mNumWord &= mOneTensArray(Val(mNumberStack(j - 1))) & Delimiter
                        mOneTens = True
                        Exit Select
                    End If

                    mNumWord &= GetTens(Val(mNumberStack(j)))

                    ' this places the tensdelimiter; check for succeeding 0
                    If Val(mNumberStack(j - 1)) <> 0 Then
                        mNumWord &= TensDelimiter
                    End If
                    mOneTens = False

                Case Else
                    ' hundreds value 
                    mNumWord &= GetOnes(Val(mNumberStack(j))) & Delimiter

                    If Val(mNumberStack(j)) <> 0 Then
                        mNumWord &= mPlaceValues(0) & Delimiter
                    End If
            End Select
        Next

        Return mNumWord & mFraction

    End Function


    Public Function DateToText(ByVal D As DateTime) As String

        Dim NumbersToText = ConvertNumberToWords(D.Year)

        Dim MonthName = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(D.Month)
        Dim dayNum As String = ""

        Select Case DateTime.Now.Day
            Case 1
                dayNum = "st"
                Exit Select
            Case 2
                dayNum = "nd"
                Exit Select
            Case 3
                dayNum = "rd"
                Exit Select
            Case 21
                dayNum = "st"
                Exit Select
            Case 22
                dayNum = "nd"
                Exit Select
            Case 23
                dayNum = "rd"
                Exit Select
            Case 31
                dayNum = "st"
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                dayNum = "th"
                Exit Select
        End Select

        Dim result = D.Day & dayNum & " of " & MonthName & " " & NumbersToText
        Return result

    End Function


End Class
```

Comment: Cool glad you got it workings.. I'll add a few suggestions below.

Comment: 1. Turn all those number names into a one line array.. from a string... like nOneTensArray = Split("ten,eleven......") Then you can easily change language by using different strings.

Comment: 2. You are passing a number as a string to the ConvertNumberToWords. However, this will prove problematic for people with different regional number settings, especially those that use a comma for a decimal place and a period for throusands separator. You would be better to accept a double and use the double.tostring method with regional setting for usa to convert it into a known string format. Your code should handle "2.000,25"